# Hypothesis testing with Neyman–Pearson Lemma

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, neyman-pearson-lemma

I have hypothesis:

$H_0: X\ \sim\ \mathcal{N}(-1,\,1)$;

$H_1: X\ \sim\ \mathcal{N}(-9,\,9)$.

Also I have significance level $\alpha = 0.2$.

I'm checking them by Neyman-Pearson Lemma.

1) Find likelihood ratio:
$\Lambda = \frac{\mathcal{N}(-9,\,9)}{\mathcal{N}(-1,\,1)}= \frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{4x^2}{9} - 4}$

2) Threshold test: 
$\Lambda \leq C \\
  x^2 \leq \frac{ln 3C}{8} + 9 \\
  x^2 \leq C^* $

**My question is how can I find $C^*$ when left part is $x^2$?**

I thought about doing this:

$ |x| \leq C^{**} $

Then $|x|$ should be folded normal distribution, but it gives wrong answer with given
significance level.

[image: Visualisation of N(-1,-1) and N(-9,9)]

Comment: Please check your algebra: I cannot reproduce any of it. Your plot indicates the second parameter in your notation is the variance, whence the density of a Normal$(-9,9)$ variable is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi9}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x+9)^2}{9}\right),$$ for instance. The likelihood ratio comes out in a form similar to what you give but with different coefficients.  After that, you must be taking logarithms, but how you compute with them is puzzling indeed.

Comment: $\Lambda = \frac{\mathcal{N}(-9,\,9)}{\mathcal{N}(-1,\,1)} = \frac{\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x+9)^2}{18}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}}} = \frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{-(x+9)^2 + 9(x+1)^2}{18}} = \frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{-x^2 - 18x - 81 + 9x^2 + 18x + 9}{18}} = \frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{8x^2 - 72}{18}} = \frac{1}{3}e^{\frac{4x^2}{9} - 4}$

$ \frac{1}{3}e^{\frac{4x^2}{9} - 4} \leq C \\
  e^{\frac{4x^2}{9} - 4} \leq 3C \\
  \frac{4x^2}{9} -4 \leq ln 3C \\
  x^2 \leq \frac{9 ln3C}{4} + 9$ Really, there are mistake in threshold. But I still have trouble with $x^2$ in threshold.

Comment: The last step is mistaken: your algebra should begin by noting $4x^2/9 \le 4 + \log(3C)$.